# SQL Server not updating data correctly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, odbc

I have a C++ application connected to a remote SQL Server over ODBC.
All SQL commands are executed with `SQLExecDirect`.

The table looks as follows, has no keys and a clustered index on `UserId`:

```
| UserId | ItemId | State |
```

To update the data of the user, I am executing the following commands

1. Update State to 'X' of all entries the user has (stored procedure)

```cpp
"{CALL uspUpdateData(%d)}"
```

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

UPDATE tblData 
SET State = 'X' 
WHERE UserId = @userId AND State = 'A';
```

2. Insert all items the user has with State 'A' (executed directly)

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO tblData 
VALUES (1, 'abc', 'A'), (1, 'def', 'A');

COMMIT;
```

3. Delete all entries of the user with state 'X' (stored procedure)

```cpp
"{CALL uspClearData(%d)}"
```

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DELETE FROM tblData 
WHERE UserId = @userId AND State = 'X';
```

My problem is that sometimes the user might end up with duplicated entries, like two times with item 'abc'. Another problem is that a user might end up with all his entries being deleted.

Could this be caused by SQL not executing the commands in the order I sent? I've tried to force the issue, but without luck. The profiler always shows the correct order of execution.

Another thing I observed was that the update and delete command are executed with `RPC:Completed`, while insert is executed with `SQL:BatchCompleted`, but couldn't find any information about this being the reason for the issue.

Any idea whether this could be an out of order issue?

Comment: The commands will always be executed in the order sent. Do you have multiple instances of your application?

Comment: It appears you are concating/interpolating parameters into the queries. This is not the correct way to do it, you should be binding parameters properly

Comment: It is only a single application that runs a single thread, so that cannot be the issue.